# Angularjs not routing

Tags: .net, angularjs

cannot route through this the `href` I have used is: `"#/Loginc"`, `"#/registers"`

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("OhpFSPA", ["ngRoute"]);
  var routes=[
      { templateUrl: "/ngviews/registers.html", controller: "HomeController" },
      { templateUrl: "/Views/Registers/Login.html", controller: "LogincController" }

  ];

      console.log("routes are initialized");
      app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider


              .when("/registers", routes[0])
              .when("/Loginc", routes[1])



              .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Loginc" });
      });

  }());
```

Comment: try `href="#!/Loginc"`

Comment: still not working @AlekseySolovey

Comment: thing is when i wrote logincontroller it stopped routing..until then it was redirecting to the html pages properly

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see what's happening in F12 Dev Tools. My guess is that requests to Login.html are getting 404/401 errors.

Is the Login.html view sitting inside an MVC folder that has a custom web.config explicitly denying access to the file? That's how it should be setup, at least by default.

If that's the case, try changing the templateUrl for the Login.html to the MVC view endpoint on the server side controller, like... /registers/login or whatever it is.